# Why do offline switching converters often use discrete rectifiers for bridge?

Tags: pcb, switch-mode-power-supply, mains, rectifier, component-selection

In conjunction with my independent study of switching converters using textbooks, I am more or less obsessively tearing apart all the low-ish power (say 5 - 25 Watt) switching converters I can find. I'm finding myself increasingly able to explain what's happening inside and generally learning a lot about the practicalities of the topic:

[image]

I was surprised to discover that all but one of the offline converters I've explored so far use *discrete* rectifier diodes to form the mains voltage rectifier bridge. This has a few downsides I can see:

- increased PCB area
- increased component population effort
- perhaps increased parasitic C and L, although I don't know that for a fact nor whether anyone would care at that particular part of the circuit

I have a couple hypotheses about why these downsides might be outweighed:

- Lower cost?
- Increased thermal coupling for better dissipation without a heat sink?

Anyway, can someone with experience with these designs help me understand the design reasoning that might explain this apparently common choice?

Comment: I'm going with "cheap cheap cheap".

Comment: I've got 3 different open frame AC-DC converters laying about.  They are rated between 40 to 200W.  All use an integrated bridge IC.

Comment: I'm voting for cost & increased heat dissipation (esp. since many of the ICs have a plastic case with lower surface area vs 4 cylindrical, often glass, individual diodes). When purchased in full reels, many discrete rectifier diodes fall to <0.01 USD/ea

Comment: Freedom of layout may or may not also play a role. But cheap is always a good bet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The installed cost of 4 diodes is less than the cost of a packaged rectifier bridge.

Cost of a 1N400x diode in quantity is maybe 0.2-0.3 cents.

That's the main reason- switching power supplies in consumer products are ruthlessly cost-reduced and any fat gets squeezed out.

Answer (score 1):

On the face of it you would think that an intergrated bridge is the answer .In 1992 I saw 4 solder paste button diodes being used where one side was soldered to a heatsink and the other side was soldered to a wire going to the PCB .It seamed crazy to me at the time . Amazingly this was all done by hand  .                 The place where I saw this was a total sweat shop and I was told that it was cheaper to do this than buy a bridge .I was also told that the hand soldering process "pre aged the diodes giving them a lower foward drop " .The pre aging could be an urban myth and the cost stuff may apply in the third world .There is one engineering reason to use 4 diodes and that is to get a better surge current rating so you have more rugged PSU when there are mains transients.In fact I have used 4 diodes sometimes .Nowdays with SMD the penalty of parts count is minimal and 4 diodes could spread the heat better.Some semiconductor manufacturers offer mains diodes in TO247 and TO220 packages which should result in lower thermal resistance than Epoxy filled bridges.